# getting 401 error when checking logged in status in react. backend uses express, passport

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

My signup request works perfectly fine, so i know the frontend and backend are hooked up correctly.

My frontend code looks like this:
I have also tried putting the axios.get request to check-login in a useEffect hook, but got the same error 401.

```js
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', loginForm);
            console.log(response.data);
            setLoginForm({
                username: '',
                password: ''
            })
            const response2 = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/check-login', {withCredentials: true});
            console.log(response2.data);
            setIsLoggedIn(response.data.loggedIn);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      }
```

My backend code looks like this:

```
app.get('/check-login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("Is Authenticated?", req.isAuthenticated());
    res.status(200).json({message: 'User is Logged in'});
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'User is not logged in'});
  }
})
```

When I make a get request to check-login with postman, it seems to work fine.
It's only when i try to login via the react app that it gives a 401 error. Here is the error in full:

> GET http://localhost:5000/check-login 401 (Unauthorized)
> handleCheckLogin

> AxiosError

```
{message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 401"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: {…}, status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n
```

Here is my cors setup:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
}));
```

Comment: please add the complete error message with your question. Also add your backend's cors setup please.

Comment: I made those edits. Thanks.

Comment: And you are sure that the session cookie is being sent with the get request? Have you checked for cookie header in your get request from devtools network tab?

Comment: Yes, there is a connect.sid cookie in the header for the request and response.